# Rename caption of figures and tables

Tags: captions

I am new to Latex. I want to rename the figures and the table as "Exhibit" instead of the standard "Figures" and "Tables". This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\title{}
\sethlcolor{yellow}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{}{3.5ex}% increased by 1ex
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \dimen@\SOUL@ulthickness
    \dimen@i=-.75ex % increased by -0.25ex
    \advance\dimen@i-.5\dimen@
    \edef\SOUL@uldepth{\the\dimen@i}%
    \let\SOUL@ulcolor\SOUL@stcolor
    \SOUL@ulpreamble
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionbiblio}{%
    \patchcmd{\std@thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
}


% define \c
%citetpos just like \citet
\DeclareRobustCommand\citetpos
{\begingroup
    \let\NAT@nmfmt\NAT@posfmt% ...except with a different name format
    \NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
    \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}

\makeatother

\makeatletter
% make numeric styles use name format
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else \NAT@nm}{\else \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}{}{}

\let\NAT@orig@nmfmt\NAT@nmfmt
\def\NAT@posfmt#1{\NAT@orig@nmfmt{#1's}}

\makeatother
\newcommand{\Y}[1]{{\color{green}#1}}
\newcommand{\N}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9}


\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}

\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=45\relax\hl{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Exhibit}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Exhibit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \rule{1cm}{1cm}
        \caption{This is a figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone point me to what is clushing with the  `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Exhibit} \renewcommand{\tablename}{Exhibit}` ?

Comment: See the babel manual section 1.15, modifying a language. In short babel is overwriting any changes whenever the language is changed. So instead you need to add your change to the appropriate language, the referred section from the babel manual shows you how.

Comment: You can use the newfloat package to create a float named exhibit, complete with its own counter, \caption and \listofexhibits.